# Initialize a 32 bit int using hex

Tags: hex

I'd like to initialize an integer using a hex value. I've tried 0x5555555555555555 and I get a compiler error stating cannot convert long to int. How do I initialize a 32 bit int with hex values?

Comment: 0x5555555555555555 requires at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The hex value you provided is 16 bytes or 64 bits which would be interpreted as a long. This value won’t fit into a int32 (which is made up of 8 bytes or 32 bits), 0x55555555 will fit.